# What is the two dot operator in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

WHAT DOES THOSE TWO DOT MEAN.. in rails

has a function like this:

```
def period
   start_date..end_date
end
```

what is it? does this generate an array?
I saw this being used in this class

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
   # ... some code is skipped here for simplicity's sake
   validate :validate_other_booking_overlap

   def period
     start_date..end_date
   end

   private

   def validate_other_booking_overlap
     other_bookings = Booking.all
     is_overlapping = other_bookings.any? from |other_booking|
       period.overlaps?(other_booking.period)
     end
     errors.add(:overlaps_with_other) if is_overlapping
   end
end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is literal syntax for an inclusive finite [`Range`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Range.html) in ruby.

> A Range represents an interval—a set of values with a beginning and an end...When used as an iterator, ranges return each value in the sequence.

Ranges can be expressed as inclusive, two dots (`..`), or exclusive, three dots (`...`). Exclusive Ranges don't include the last element.

Before 2.6 all Ranges were finite (syntactically required a beginning and an end; although the end could be `Float::INFINITY` [inversely  `-Float::INFINITY` for beginning] so technically not all Ranges were "finite").

In 2.6 "endless ranges" were implemented using the syntax `x..`.

As of 2.7 Ranges can be "beginless" using the syntax `..x`

Both beginless and endless Ranges are "semi-infinite" according to the documentation and can be expressed as either inclusive or exclusive. (Being honest I am not sure what an exclusive endless Range would be; although the syntax has creative uses [see below])

As a sidenote:  (**TL;DR**)

Looping through every `Booking` is a bad idea from a performance standpoint.

A better idea would be to offload this to the database using something like:

```
def validate_other_booking_overlap
  overlaps_bookings = Booking
    .where(start_date: period)
    .or(Booking.where(end_date: period))
    .or(
      Booking.where(
        Booking.arel_table[:start_date].gt(start_date)
          .and(Booking.arel_table[:end_date].lt(end_date))))
    .where.not(id: id)
    .exists?
  errors.add(:overlaps_with_other) if overlaps_bookings
end
```

Rails (Arel) converts finite Ranges in a WHERE condition to a SQL BETWEEN clause, so this query condition would be:

```
WHERE
((bookings.start_date BETWEEN '####-##-##' AND '####-##-##' 
  OR bookings.end_date BETWEEN '####-##-##' AND '####-##-##')
  OR (
    bookings.start_date > '####-##-##' 
    AND bookings.end_date < '####-##-##'
  ))
  AND bookings.id != # -- IS NOT NULL on create
```

In newer versions of rails (>=6.0.3 and ruby >= 2.7) this:

```
Booking.arel_table[:start_date].gt(start_date)
  .and(Booking.arel_table[:end_date].lt(end_date))
```

Can be substituted with this

```
Booking.where(start_date: start_date..., end_date:...end_date))
```

because now Rails (Arel) treats Ranges as follows:

- `x..y` attribute BETWEEN x AND y ( e.g. attribute >= x AND attribute <= y )
- `x...y` attribute >= x AND attribute < y
- `x..` attribute >= x
- `x...` attribute >= x (this was a decision made by the rails team based on the Ruby implementation/interpretation of endless exclusive ranges)
- `where.not(attribute: ..x)` attribute > x
- `..x` attribute <= x
- `...x` attribute < x

...And now I believe we've come full circle.

**UPDATE**

Due to @max's comments you could use the `OVERLAPS` function (where the database supports it) as follows

```
def validate_other_booking_overlap
  left = Arel::Nodes::Grouping.new(
    [Booking.arel_table[:start_date],
    Booking.arel_table[:end_date]])
  right = Arel::Nodes::Grouping.new(
    [Arel::Nodes::UnaryOperation.new(
      'DATE', 
      [Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(start_date - 1)]),
    Arel::Nodes::UnaryOperation.new(
      'DATE', 
      [Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(end_date + 1)])])
  condition = Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('OVERLAPS', left, right)
  errors.add(:overlaps_with_other) if Booking.where.not(id: id).where(condition).exists?
end
```

Comment: Good answer. On Postgres you can use the [OVERLAPS operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-datetime.html) to create a much simpler and more efficient query. Its part of the SQL standard but notably not supported by MySQL.

Comment: `Booking.where("(booking.starts_at, booking.ends_at) OVERLAPS (?, ?)",  start_date, end_date)`. Postgres also has native tsrange types that can speed up performance critical applications with GiST indexes.

Comment: @max that certainly is simpler and I was unaware of the function. I try to avoid raw SQL wherever possible because I find it can create a maintenance and portability nightmare.

Comment: I have a feeling that it could be written with Arel :). This is one of those case where it can definately be worth it for performance.

Comment: @max aparently [`Arel::Nodes::Overlaps`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f95c0b7e96eb36bc3efc0c5beffbb9e84ea664e4/activerecord/lib/arel/nodes/infix_operation.rb#L56) exists as a predication (an `InfixOperation`) but is implemented as `left && right` suggesting it was implemented for Array. I would implement similarly but as mentioned would likely implement type casting as a `UnaryOperation` so we can use `TIME '7:15:00'` syntax for postgres. Only thing I don't like is that end_first == start_second does not constitute an "OVERLAP" but instead is treated as contiguous.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow but if its implemented as a array it will treat the left and right as values to be escaped? Could you still get `TIME '7:15:00'` by making it a SQLiteral?

Comment: @max I meant that Arel's Overlaps class is intended for array overlap rather than interval overlap. I update my post as to how I would go about implementing interval overlap as a standalone but if I was going to implement as an Arel Class it would an Infix and yes left and right would be the responsibility of the caller but if I was going to use SQLiteral I might as well have just used the raw SQL you originally commented.