# How can i create a query without string in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this query comparing dates

```
project.active.where("delivery_date <= :date", date: Date.today)
```

i would like dont use string like this

```
 project.active.where(delivery_date: delivery_date <= Date.today)
```

but does not worked, i got this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting `end'
```

Comment: Why do you want to use strings ? I don't know any reason to avoid use strings.

You can do this query like this: 

    project.active.where('delivery_date <= ?', Date.today)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Arel`, but you're not gaining anything here, if anything it makes it less readable:

```rb
Project.active.where(
  Project.arel_table[:delivery_date].lteq(Date.today)
)
```

Comment: In modern rails `delivery_date: ..Date.today` will produce `<=`

Comment: @engineersmnky and for > ?

Comment: @engineersmnky what is the name of that operator?

Comment: @engineersmnky doesn't seem to work for `>` https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.1.1/activerecord/lib/arel/predications.rb#L53

Comment: lol, this works though `Project.where.not(delivery_date: ..Date.today).to_sql` `"SELECT \"projects\".* FROM \"projects\" WHERE \"projects\".\"delivery_date\" > '2023-11-08'"`, this is the most wtf rails momemt i've had in a while.

Comment: @Alex thank you for the correction and also that is awful.

Comment: @Alex it appears this was [Discussed and Rejected](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/47345) based on reasonable arguments. That being said I still disagree with it especially given how much sugar rails already pours on top of ruby.

Answer (score 0):

```
where(delivery_date: Date.new..Date.today)
```

or Date.new can be replaced with the starting of the server/db.
you can do this too but this just compares with a very long range. Why won't you want to use strings?

Comment: Ranges do not result in `Array`s. Bound Inclusive Ranges (which is what you have presented) will result in `BETWEEN range.begin and range.end`, other ranges of varying types will result in different SQL results [Here's a complete rundown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70809495/what-is-the-two-dot-operator-in-rails/70809569#70809569)